# How to make the scope optional in google-singin?

Tags: oauth-2.0, electron, google-oauth, google-signin

I want users to be able to sign in with their google account regardless if they allow for calendar access or not. For some reason now it is not possible to click `Allow` without checking the checkbox.
Here is my code:

```
this.auth = new ElectronGoogleOAuth2(
  process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  ["profile", "email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"],
  {
    successRedirectURL: process.env.ELECTRON_SUCCESS_REDIRECT_URL,
    loopbackInterfaceRedirectionPort: process.env.ELECTRON_LOOPBACK_REDIRECT_PORT,
  },
);
```

Is there any way I can make this scope optional `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`.

[image]

Comment: Let the user authenticate without the calendar scope. Then later when required update the required scopes. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth

Comment: @JohnHanley and if I want to lower the scope, let's say from full calendar access to just read calendar access?

Comment: Ask for the scope that you need when required.